# Issue with Gifted Chat, the messages jump up the screen on text input

Tags: react-native

I'm using Gifted Chat for react native, but I'm getting strange behavior. When keyboard is down, messages are fine. When I tap on the keyboard to have it come up, it's also fine.. but the moment I start typing, the messages jump up. The only way to get them back again is to close the keyboard. Here is how it looks:

[image: img]

What am I doing wrong here? Here is the code:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      behavior="padding"
      keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.select({
        ios: () => 0,
        android: () => 100
      })()}
    >
      <GiftedChat
        handleChoosePhoto={handleChoosePhoto}
        forceGetKeyboardHeight
        showUserAvatar
        renderChatFooter={renderChatFooter}
        isAnimated
        scrollToBottom
        onInputTextChanged={e => emitTyping(user._id, otherUser, e)}
        showAvatarForEveryMessage
        messages={messages}
        onSend={msg => onSend(msg)}
        user={user}
      />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

This component is returned as a functional component, not wrapped in anything else and not in conflict with anything else. The strange thing is that if I get rid of `behavior="padding"`, it doesn't jump... but then the `TextInput` element is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by removing `forceGetKeyboardHeight`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need KeyboardAvoidingView in giftedChat the component handles it's own keyboard so just remove that component